# Pandas: How to map the dictionary of a column as a separate column name and its corresponding value

Tags: pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in below format,

```
ip_df=pd.DataFrame({'class':['I','II','III'],'details':[{'sec':'A','kinder':'yes'},{'sec':'B'}]
ip_df:
    class   details
0   I       {'sec':'A','kinder':'yes'}
1   II      {'sec':'B'}
2   III     None
```

How to map the dictionary keys as a column name and dictionary values to its respective column of "details" column?

```
 op_df:
      class    detail                     sec    kinder
 0    I        {'sec':'A','kinder':'yes'} A      yes
 1    II       {'sec':'B'}                B      None
 2    III      None                       None   None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is not important convert each row to `Series`:

```
ip_df = ip_df.join(ip_df['details'].apply(pd.Series))
print (ip_df)
  class                        details  sec kinder
0     I  {'sec': 'A', 'kinder': 'yes'}    A    yes
1    II                   {'sec': 'B'}    B    NaN
2   III                           None  NaN    NaN
```

Another solution is remove missing values or `None`s and create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
s = ip_df['details'].dropna()
ip_df = ip_df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index))
print (ip_df)
  class                        details  sec kinder
0     I  {'sec': 'A', 'kinder': 'yes'}    A    yes
1    II                   {'sec': 'B'}    B    NaN
2   III                           None  NaN    NaN
```

Last if necessary convert missing values to `None`s:

```
ip_df = ip_df.mask(ip_df.isna(), None)
print (ip_df)
  class                        details   sec kinder
0     I  {'sec': 'A', 'kinder': 'yes'}     A    yes
1    II                   {'sec': 'B'}     B   None
2   III                           None  None   None
```